# How to check less than condition in Kubernetes annotation?

Tags: kubernetes, annotations

I have a annotation added like this for rbac definition.

```
Annotations:  expires-at: 2020-07-24T19:24:42Z
```

I want to filter only the Kubernetes resources that is already expired based upon this annotation.
I tried below..but it does not work.. "<" is considering the following as file name.

```
kubectl get rbacdefinition  --field-selector metadata.annotations.expires-at<$(date -u  '+%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%SZ')
```

Please let me know how to solve this.

Comment: https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/overview/working-with-objects/field-selectors/#supported-fields. The field selectors doesnt have a supported field for pess or greater than so it doesnt work.

Comment: In case you are looking for some tool to cleanup all the expired k8s resources then check this out https://github.com/hjacobs/kube-janitor

Answer (score 0):

Posting this answer as community wiki for better visibility as good answers were posted in comments.

As was mentioned by `@tarun khosla`, when you are using selector operators, only `=`, `==` and `!=` are supported. Thus operators like `<`, `>`, `=<` will not work. It's described in [Kubernetes docs](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/overview/working-with-objects/field-selectors/#supported-fields)

Another good point was provided by `@mchawre` to use 3rd party software which is [Kube Janitor](https://github.com/hjacobs/kube-janitor).

As workaroud you could consider to use:

`kubectl describe <resource> | grep expires-at: > expiration.txt`

or

`kubectl describe all -n <namespace> | grep expires-at: -A 5 > expiration.txt`

However, depends on resource and number of annotations you could get many irrelevant information.

Answer (score 0):

The answer from what I'm seeing is that no, `<, >, REGEXP(), and IN()`, basically what you'd expect in a database, is not there.  And you're right to ask because the documentation I've found:

```
https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/overview/working-with-objects/field-selectors/
```

Doesn't explicitly state this.

Takeaway rule: **NEVER** use kubernetes resources as you would use a database or you'll be dealing with issues like this.  Besides `=` and `!=`, `>` and `<` are the most minimally intuitively expected comparators, and they're not there.